# Calling an x86 dll from a VS 2010/DotNet 4.0 x86 targeted app

Tags: dll, x86, 64-bit, access-violation

I'm getting an 'AccessViolationException' 'Attempted to read or write protected memory' when calling a method in an x86 dll when running on an x64 platform (Windows 7).  Everything works great on x86 platforms.

I've read many, many posts about similar problems but haven't been able to get my code to work.

I'm in the process of trying to make our old x86 app work happily on Windows 7 (x64) and Server 2008 R2 (x64).  The app is an assortment of VB6 , VB.Net, C#, MicroFocus COBOL and C++.  (We couldn't think of any other languages to throw in at the time).  The DotNet code was originally written in Visual Studio 2003 for DotNet 1.1.  I've ported the code up to Visual Studio 2010 and DotNet 4.0.  I've set the target for all the projects to x86.  When I call into un-managed 32 bit dll's I get the above error.

Our InstallShield setup routine is installing the x86 dll's into C:\Windows\sysWOW64 instead of C:\Windows\System32.  This behavior seems correct.  The dll's are some COBOL object code and runtime components linked together into a 'C Style' dll.  I don't think the problem has to do with COBOL or the linking process as I also ported up a sample app from Code Project with a VB.Net WinForms app that calls a simple C++ dll, all targeted to x86.  I get the same error there.  I've also tried building a C++ command line app to call the dll.  The Load Library succeeds.  GetProcAddress succeeds.  Calling the function pointer for the particular method fails.  Our VB6 apps can call the dll's just fine when running on Windows 7 x64.  I've also tried turning off UAC and setting the requestedExecutionLevel in the manifest to the highestAvailable.  I've tried running as administrator.

Seems like this should work, but not sure what to try next.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On x64 .net programs will be run as 64-bit programs and cannot call 32bit-dlls.

Try compiling the application with target x86 instead of "Any Target". You can also force the 
target of the built .exe with the .Net CorFlags.exe utility to run in 32bit-mode.

Of course your program will then run in the 32bit environment, especially it will only have a maximum of 2gb of RAM.

Comment: The OP says, "...set the target for all projects to x86".

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes, I've already done that - all projects are set to target x86 and the access violation error is there.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Good news,

We investigated DEP as a possible cause of the problem as we saw that even our VB6 code will fail when DEP is turned on.  We noticed that the VB.Net code was failing in the same way as VB6 when DEP was on.  Apparently our COBOL dll's do something that DEP isn't happy with. Unfortunately the DotNet assemblies don't seem to respect the operating system DEP setting, so you have to turn off DEP with using editbin.exe:

editbin.exe /nxnocompat:no

I still have to test it on our full application, but it looks like we have a solution!